# Test Stored Procedure against data in Database project

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am using ssdt in VS2012. I am writing a stored procedure and now I want to test this SP against some data.
How can I do it without creating this SP on actual SQL Server Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't want to build the database? This can be done without having to use a full SQL Server instances as SSDT comes packaged with LocalDB. Press F5 to build a database from your database project and add some data to the resulting database.